# Can the query results form three different tables go into one array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to pull all of the records in each of these tables that have a value in Games.date_added that is greater than an inputed date.  Trying to pull all the new records.

Can I do that all in one query?  Or is it easier to just add a date_added field to each table and query each table separately?

> **GAMES**
>   id
>   date_added
>   game_name
>   release_date
>   game_category
>   game_type
>   game_console
>
> **TROPHIES**
>   trophies_id
>   game_name
>   tr_name 
>   tr_description
>   tr_color
>   tr_ach_value
>
> **TROPHY_TOTALS**
>   trophy_totals_id
>   game_name
>   bronze_ttl
>   silver_ttl
>   gold_ttl
>   plat_ttl
>   hidden_ttl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be much better and clearer if you do 3 separate queries. Each one will give you a different amount of rows. The query given by glglgl that uses 2 joins will result in multiplied rows from the games table. This is because tropies and tropy totals can contain multiple records with same game. Of course if game_name is a unique column than the join will be OK.

Comment: There are multiple records in trophies with the same game name.

Comment: In this case stay with separate queries. There is no point in joining data. But the hint given by glglgl abiut ID's is also a good idea. Change the way you connect data. Game name is a string it can differ due to a single space and the conection will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would surely better to have your foreign key fields in `TROPHIES` and `TROPHY_TOTALS` be `id` resp. `game_id` rather than `game_name`.

This said, I will concentrate on your current table structure.

```
SELECT <wanted fields>
    FROM GAMES
    LEFT JOIN TROPHIES USING (game_name)
    LEFT JOIN TROPHY_TOTALS USING (game_name)
    WHERE date_added > <given>
```